# Maven / Eclipse / WTP - /src/main/resources not deployed

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I have a Maven/Web/Eclipse project running.

When I deploy in Eclipse, the contents of /src/main/resources are not deployed.

Here's my `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="Grapevine">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="Grapevine"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/Grapevine/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Note - if I do `mvn install` the war is built correctly, including the resources files.

I'm using:

- m2e 0.10.2.20100623-1649
- Eclipse 3.5 (20090621-0832)
- WTP 3.1.1

What am I missing?

Comment: Does a mvn clean package work correctly which means to get a correct .war file ?

Comment: Yep.  Building from mvn works fine.  It's Eclipse/WTP that seems to have the problem.

Comment: Are you using m2eclipse?

Comment: @Pascal - Yes.  Environment details updated in post.

Comment: Same here for using eclipse and maven and running 'mvn jetty:run' inside eclipse. Often, the resources are removed from the target/classes folder and therefore my spring container doesn't start. This issue is very annoying. Still I couldn't figure out how to solve it but maybe my former post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111927/the-eclipse-autobuilder-often-ignore-the-resource-directory can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the compiler, by any chance, filtering the output folders?

Check if project properties -> Java Build Path -> source folders -> src/main/resources > excluded is anything other than (None).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I'd already checked this.