# How to make Maven deploy src/main/resources?

Tags: maven, deployment, resources

I have a Maven project. It is successfully deploying the jar file. I also want it to deploy the contents of **src/main/resources**.

mvn deploy does not deploy the resources.

How can I make it do that?

I read about using the copy file task and other workaround methods, but I want to use Maven's default behavior for deploying, which I thought would include the resources.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685461/maven-eclipse-wtp-src-main-resources-not-deployed

Answer (score 1):

The folder src/main/resources contains resources which will be packaged into the jar file which means in other words it is already deployed within the created jar file.

Comment: So Maven't can't deploy files other than the jar...the issue I'm having is that `getResource` cannot access files inside jars, so the files need to be deployed separately.

Comment: `getResource` can access files within JARs, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905888/within-resources-in-jar?rq=1